# Motivation to extend sin and cos to angles > 90 degree

Tags: mathematics, trigonometry

What was *from a historical point of view* the motivation to extend the definition of sin and cos to angles larger than 90 degree?

Comment: Sine and cosine are ratios of a right triangle, but all triangles in general (right, acute, and obtuse) can still have angles that can be compared to the right triangle, so these ratios remain applicable.

Comment: These are studied in Euclid's Elements, but their study may be dated even earlier.

Comment: That obtuse triangles exist? Once trigonometry was developed they wanted the laws of sines and cosines to apply to them too, for example. Did you mean > 360 degrees? It was the formal attitude of 17th and 18th centuries to extend algebraic manipulations as far and wide as they would bear, compare to [Generality of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generality_of_algebra). And the series formulas they had for sin and cos could bear all real, and later even complex, numbers.

Comment: this a guess: fourier trying to sove PDE using trigonometric series?